# Can somebody tell me why this java code got different answers while running from Mac(or unixlike) from Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, macos

I run this code in eclipse on my Windows 7 system which returns string with spaces which Macs don't have. It is not the problem of eclipse I've tested with different IDEs. So can somebody tell me why?

```
public class CharPro {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] foo = new char[28];
        printCharArray(foo);
        foo[0]='0';
        foo[1]='1';
        printCharArray(foo);
        printCharArray(reverse(foo));
    }

    private static void printCharArray(char[] A) {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i)
            System.out.print(A[i]);
        System.out.println();
    }

    private static char[] reverse(char[] A){
        int l=A.length;
        char[] B=new char[l];
        for (int i=0;i<l;i++){
            B[i]=A[l-1-i];
        }
        return B;
    }

}
```

Comment: I would expect this to be just a different console thing between Mac and Windows; the code should run the same but the way the consoles display it may differ.

Comment: Really? But I don't think windows would print '\0' by space.

Comment: I've just written a short test program, and can confirm that in the default console font, the NUL character is an empty glyph (i.e., a space).

Comment: Thanks guys! Yes, even I print one char '\0', it will show a space in Windows.

Comment: But as I remember, while in C language, when you hit the '\0', it is the end of the char array. So how do java know it is the end of the array since java don't care about hitting the '\0'.

Comment: @Elizabeth You explicitly tell which chars to print giving the length. Strings know their length and has it stored, instead of needing to look for the termination character. This is where Java shows it is not C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please notice you are not assigning values to all 28 positions in your `foo` array.  These uninitialized locations then still contain an ASCII zero which you then print out and which the terminal emulators responsible for interpreting your output and showing the interpretation to you treat differently.

Please try adding a loop after your `new` assigning an actual, visible character - like `A` or  to each position in `foo`, and try again.  You should then see identical output on all platforms.

Comment: Yes,I know how to make them platform free. I just want to know why they look different in different platforms. As you said, there must be '\0' inside those uninitialized chars. So you think it is the problem of consoles which interpreted '\0' differently?

Comment: If you are trying to print an array of chars with System.out.print on Windows there is no reason why there would be spaces between them. Check that it's not something from your IDE(s) preferences.

Comment: Yes.  Most likely depending on the font used.

Comment: Java attempts to guarantee that the code itself will operate identically, regardless of the platform.  But it cannot control platform characteristics such as how characters are displayed in the OS-defined "console".

Comment: Thanks all guys. Really appreciate it! I think it is fun, I went to lab hour and the TAs can't answer it.

Comment: But as I remember, while in C language, when you hit the '\0', it is the end of the char array. So how do java know it is the end of the array since java don't care about hitting the '\0'.

Comment: Strings are implemented differently in Java than in C, and the length of the string is explicitly stored in Java.  Hence the `\0` value does not have to have a special meaning for Java strings.